# JQuery css(...,...) function on click() working on JSFiddle but not Firefox/Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a map with several printers placed around, and upon hovering over the printer, a list of local printers will appear. I want to convert the "hovering" to an action upon "clicking" through JQuery.

Here is my code (which uses HTML, CSS, and JQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/K2e4E/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#r1242').click( function() {
                $('#p1242').css("display","block");
          });
    });
```

It may not help to read all of the code; however, I have provided all of it. The pictures of the printers are maligned when placed into jsfiddle, but my emphasis is upon the left, bottom printer image. When clicked, it'll make the list of available printers stay, as opposed to disappearing after hovering away from it.

This works in jsfiddle but when I open my file on either Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome, this doesn't apply. The list of available printers for that specific printer doesn't show up. Why is this?

UPDATE:

I believe there may be an error with my linking between HTML, CSS, and JQuery, but all these changes work in JSFiddle, but when I apply the changes locally and try to open my file in a web browser, the JQuery functions never apply. This is what I have in the  of the HTML file.

```
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="main.css"/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery in the document?

Comment: The jsfiddle link includes all of my code. In the <head> of the HTML file, I included "<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>" and "<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>". I saved the jquery-ui.js in my local directory, which is why I'm not linking it to a website. So yes, I included jQuery in my document. @mdesdev

Comment: I didn't ask you did you include jQueryUI in the document. I asked you did you include **jQuery**

Answer (score 0):

Using room 1463 as an example.

Add this class to your CSS;

```
.show{
 display:block!important;   
}
```

Comment out the hover;

```
/* #r1463:hover > #p1463 {
    display:block;
}
*/
```

Then in your HTML;

```
<div id="r1463" onclick="$('#p1463').toggleClass('show');">
```

Updated fiddle here;
http://jsfiddle.net/K2e4E/2/

Answer (score 0):

As Darren said above you have to comment out the style you applied in hover.
But instead of adding one more class show, you can use

```
$('#p1463').toggle();
```

Instead of using "id" add common class for the printer image div (such as #r1411) as well as the div(such as  #p1242) ,so you can have single click function to show the pop up for all .